# How to require node modules correctly in node.exe of node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, module, socket.io, npm

Recently there is a newer version of node.js which supports npm for windows.

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) 
And i've installed socket.io successfully on windows through npm (though some failed, like JSDOM)

However when I require the module the followings fails:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(1234);
```

and also

```
var io = require("./lib/node_modules/socket.io/index.js").listen(1234);
```

Which shows "Cannot find module "socket.io"

However this works:

```
var io = require('/NodeDev/lib/node_modules/socket.io/index.js').listen(1234);
```

Here is where my stuff are placed:

> folder socket.io : in D:\NodeDev\lib\node_modules\
>
> node.exe : in D:\NodeDev\bin\
>
> my script : in D:\NodeDev\TestProject\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem when dealing with generally available packages in Windows.  It worked when I installed the packages directly into my project:

```
cd myProject
npm install socket.io
```

It then gets installed into the `myProject/node_modules` folder.  At that time, doing a `require('socket.io')` works for me.

Comment: Also of note, using node and npm in Windows is a bit of a nightmare right now.  You might consider using cloud9ide.com, a linux VM to run node in, or something for the next little while.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue with the same method as yours!(Though I figured it out myself actually :p) And I will try cloud9ide.com too, thanks all :)

Comment: It is actually recommended to install all npm modules (that aren't tools like `coffee`) locally like this rather than globally - it means different projects can target a specific version of an npm modules and the project dir has everything it needs to run so you can easily deploy it.

Comment: I like what you say, Mr. @CallumRogers

Comment: @BrianGenisio You Rock!