# What is the difference between require('mypackage.js') and require('mypackage')?

Tags: node.js, require

Both these `require` statements appear to work the same way:

`var Mypackage = require('mypackage.js');`

`var Mypackage require('mypackage');`

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: The community tends to use the second.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
Module.prototype.load = function(filename) {
  debug('load ' + JSON.stringify(filename) +
        ' for module ' + JSON.stringify(this.id));

  assert(!this.loaded);
  this.filename = filename;
  this.paths = Module._nodeModulePaths(path.dirname(filename));

  var extension = path.extname(filename) || '.js';
  if (!Module._extensions[extension]) extension = '.js';
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
  this.loaded = true;
};
```

1. [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) looks to see if the given module is a core module. (e.g. `http`, `fs`, etc.)
   Always takes the precedence in the loading modules.
2. If the given module is not a core module (e.g. `http`, `fs`, etc.), Node.js will then begin to search for a directory named, *`node_modules`*. 
   It will start in the current directory (relative to the currently-executing file in [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org)) and then work its way up the folder hierarchy, checking each level for a node_modules folder.
   Once [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) finds the `node_modules` folder, it will then attempt to load the given module either as a (.js) JavaScript file or as a named sub-directory; if it finds the named sub-directory, it will then attempt to load the file in various ways. So, for example
3. If you make a request to load the module, "utils" and its a directory not a .js file then:
   [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) will search a hierarchical directory for `node_modules` and
   `utils` in the following ways: 

   `./node_modules/utils.js`
   `./node_modules/utils/index.js`

    `./node_modules/utils/package.json`
4. If [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) still can't find the file in above steps, Node.js will then start to look into the directory paths from environment variables i.e. **`NODE_PATH`** set on your machine(obviously set by Node.JS installer file if you are on windows)
   Not Found in all the above steps then, prints a stack trace to [stder](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_error_data)
   *E.g.*: **`Error:`**`Cannot find module 'yourfile'`

   For more information: link is [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) even the *cyclic require()* is explained very well.

Comment: You are not convinced with answer? Consider above logic and think you are writing an algorithm and then go through this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency)